# Change the size of math symbols so that they are the same size as $T$

Tags: math-mode, relsize

I would like to change the size $\bigvee$ so that the lowest point of the character is at the baseline and the character is no taller than an upper case character, say $T$.

```
\documentclass[paper=letter,fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{relsize}
    \begin{document}
    This is a textstyle big wedge $\textstyle{\bigwedge} T$.
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ordinary commands `\wedge` and `\vee` may suit your needs:

`$T\wedge T\vee T$`

[image]

But if you want to resize to match a `T`, you can use the `scalerel` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=letter,fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}

\newcommand{\newwedge}{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\bigwedge}{T}}}
\newcommand{\newvee}{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\bigvee}{T}}}

\begin{document}
$T\newwedge T$

$\newwedge T$

$\newwedge$

$A_{S\newwedge T_{X\newwedge Y}}$ 

\end{document}
```

As an alternative, you could scale the `\vee` command which gives a slightly different shape:

[image]

```
\newcommand{\newwedge}{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\wedge}{T}}}
\newcommand{\newvee}{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\vee}{T}}}
```

Comment: One reason to prefer ordinary `\wedge` is that the rescaled `\bigwedge` ends up (probably inevitably) with a lighter-than normal line weight.

Comment: @Sandy G Using overleaf to compile $\wedge T\vee T$ the $\wedge$ and $\vee$ are the height of lower case characters. My question was poorly worded. I would like the join character to be the height of $T$ but stand-alone without the $T$. I tried converting your solution to a function with one variable but that didn't work.

Comment: @Jay: Relative sizes of characters will depend on the font you're using. I made some edits. Does this do what you want? You can use `\newwedge` and `\newvee` anywhere in math mode, as stand-alone characters or as binary operations.